# Decode Nested JSON REST Api Response in to Array of Structs

Tags: swift, rest, swiftui

I am trying to parse the response of  https://swapi.dev/api/people/ in to a `List` but I can't seem to get it work due to the nested response structure instead of a flat response.

This is my `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private let charactersURL = URL(string: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/")!

    @State private var characters: [Character] = []


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                List {
                    ForEach(characters, id: \.self) { character in
                        NavigationLink(destination: CharacterView(character: character)) {
                            Text(character.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: loadCharacter)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Swapi Api Client")

        }

    }

    private func loadCharacter() {

        let request = URLRequest(url: charactersURL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let charactersResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Character].self, from: data.results) {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.characters = charactersResponse.results
                    }
                }
            }

        }.resume()
    }

}
```

I have a `CharactersResponse` struct:

```
struct CharactersResponse {
    let count: Int
    let next: String
    let previous: NSNull
    let results: [Character]
}
```

and a `Character` struct:

```
struct Character: Decodable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let height: Int
    let mass: String
    let hairColor: String
    let skinColor: String
    let eyeColor: String
    let birthYear: String
    let gender: String
    let homeworld: String
    let films: [String]
    let species: [String]
    let vehicles : [String]
    let starships: [String]
    let created: String
    let edited: String
    let url: String
}
```

The error I get is `Value of type 'Data' has no member 'results'` but I'm not sure how to fix it so that the `CharactersResponse` `results` are parsed in to an array of `Character` structs.

[image]

Comment: You need to make `CharactersResponse`  decodable, and decode that with `JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersResponse.self, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the raw data and the deserialized structs

Replace

```
if let charactersResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Character].self, from: data.results) { ...
```

with

```
if let charactersResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersResponse.self, from: data) { ...
```

And adopt `Decodable` in `CharactersResponse`

```
struct CharactersResponse : Decodable { ...
```

You might also replace `NSNull` with an optional of the expected type

---

Never `try?` in a `JSONDecoder` context. `catch` a potential error and print it.

```
do {   
    let charactersResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersResponse.self, from: data) { ...

} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: thanks! If I change to using the `do` I get `Variable used within its own initial value` : `do {
                    let charactersResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersResponse.self, from: data) {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.characters = charactersResponse.results
                        }
                    }

                } catch { print(error) }`

Comment: I'm not familiar with SwiftUI. Maybe the `withAnimation` expression is at the wrong place